# Can't sign in with MS Lync

Tags: ms-office, microsoft

Since I updated OS X to 10.8.5 a week ago, I have issues signing in with Microsoft Lync: the program crashes every time. I never had issues before so I thought the latest OS update caused the issue, however all my colleagues can use Lync as before.

I installed all Microsoft updates as well ...

Lync returns the following error details

Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Date/Time: 2013-10-22 09:06:43 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Lync
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Lync
Application Signature: UCCP
Application Version: 14.0.0.110823
Crashed Module Name: libsystem_c.dylib
Crashed Module Version: unknown
Crashed Module Offset: 0x000026c0
Blame Module Name: Microsoft Lync
Blame Module Version: 14.0.0.110823
Blame Module Offset: 0x01f098f7
Application LCID: 1031
Extra app info: Reg=English Loc=0x0407
Crashed thread: 0

Any ideas? thx!

Answer (score 2):

Solved this today. I'm not sure what finally solved it but this is what I did ...

1. Install the latest Mountain Lion Update which was published today
2. Completely uninstall Lync as described here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691870 
   Reinstall Lync + do the Lync update to v14.0.6
3. Change my password - as my old one contained a German special character.