# Microsoft Lync Mac crashes on 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: ms-office, macos

I have a similar problem like [another user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105991/cant-sign-in-with-ms-lync) had and followed all possible steps including reinstalling and cleaning up Keychain etc before.

The first time I start Lync after a reinstall, I can even see a Menu bar for some seconds. But before any window gets rendered, the Crash Reporter opens.

This is what the error said:

> Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0
>
> Error Signature: Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Date/Time: 2013-10-30
>   13:23:14 +0000 Application Name: Microsoft Lync Application Bundle ID:
>   com.microsoft.Lync Application Signature: UCCP Application Version:
>   14.0.6.130930 Crashed Module Name: libcorecrypto.dylib Crashed Module Version: unknown Crashed Module Offset: 0x0002783a Blame Module Name:
>   Microsoft Lync Blame Module Version: 14.0.6.130930 Blame Module
>   Offset: 0x002cc862 Application LCID: 1031 Extra app info: Reg=English
>   Loc=0x0407 Crashed thread: 0

Any Ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete

```
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/MicrosoftLyncRegistrationDB.xxxx.plist
~/library/preferences/com.microsoft.lync.plist
```

and check in

```
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/
```

for additional files with `lync` or `Lync` in the name (delete them as well). Then restart Lync.

Comment: I have been struggling with persistent Lync/libcorecrypto crashes under my primary account. No crashes under newly created "test" accounts on the host, however. I've googled around for solutions for days. Everyone keeps offering the tired ~/Library/Preferences/ kind of suggestions or digging out certs in Keychain. None worked. Watching fs_usage inspired me to go blast away /var/folders/* in single user mode. BINGO. Joy.

Comment: I removed all the files (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945448(v=office.14).aspx), rebooted, and removed /var/folders/* as another user, then re-installed Lync and it finally started working again.